# Pivot rows to columns without aggregate - in snowflake (sql)

Tags: sql, json, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a way to pivot rows to columns without perform an aggregation. I've already tried to convert the value to string and perform max/min, and it still refers to the value as a number and returns the max/min, leaving out the rest of the data.

The initial query is:
  `select  * table,lateral flatten(input =>APINVOICELINES,RECURSIVE => TRUE) where id = 29604361`

result for key and value:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| id | "3" |
| id | "4" |
| id | "5" |

every time I perform pivot with max(value) I get row with id "5" only, and I perform pivot with min(value) I get the row with "3" only.
for example:

| status | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "3" |

I expect to get 3 rows, "3","4" and "5"

| status | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "3" |
| 1 | "4" |
| 1 | "5" |

How do I do this?

In addition, if you know a better way to flatten data in pattern "[{},{},{}] in snowflake to rows, I'd love to know.

Thank you.

I tried all known agg functions, I also tried to convert the value to varchar before pivoting, but it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide the queries that you are executing?  You are providing bits and pieces of information, but not all of the details needed for somebody to help you.  For example, where does the mysterious "status = 1" come from?

Comment: status is one of the fields in the original table, let's say I have status, key, value


SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    status,key, value
  FROM
    table
)
  AS source
PIVOT
(
  max(value)
    FOR key IN (
      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
    )
)
  AS pvt(
  )

Comment: Why are you pivoting the result of the flatten then?  You already have the data flattened in the manner you need it in, you just need to choose the right fields in your select of the flatten statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your flatten statement below, you are already creating the data in the record that you need them in.  There is no need to pivot or aggregate this data from what I can tell from the detail of your question:

```
select  * 
from table t,
lateral flatten(input =>APINVOICELINES,RECURSIVE => TRUE) f
where id = 29604361;
```

Just request the correct fields from each:

```
select  t.source, f.value 
from table t,
lateral flatten(input =>APINVOICELINES,RECURSIVE => TRUE) f
where id = 29604361;
```

I posted this as an answer, because it is easier to see than in the comments, but if this is not what you are asking, then please let me know...I will delete.

Comment: I want each key to become a column, transpose rows to columns

Comment: I actually got a good answer from chatGPT:
SELECT 
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'age' THEN value END) AS age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'name' THEN value END) AS name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'city' THEN value END) AS city
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        attribute,
        value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, attribute ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM my_table
)
GROUP BY id, rn
ORDER BY id;

Comment: Your comment about wanting each key to become a column would have been helpful in your original request.  For future reference, if you want a good answer on Stackoverflow, provide all of the details.